# How to exit a position and cancel all pending orders at the same time in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I am developing a strategy that uses pending stop orders, and using strategy.exit function for stop loss, but some pending orders remain in order book and get filled after the stop loss is triggered, is there a way to prevent this behavior, i am using below code:

```
strategy.entry("Buy Stop",long=true,stop=lastFractalHigh,when=canBuy)
strategy.entry("Buy Stop",long=true,stop=lastFractalHigh,when=stillCanBuy)
strategy.exit(id="SL",from_entry="Buy Stop",stop=lastFractalLow)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strategy.cancel_all`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dcancel_all) to cancel all pending orders.